# I have an error replacing window.onload with window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I have an error replacing `window.onload` with `window.addEventListener`.

The short javascript program below

http://enclick.com/widgets/freelancer/test2.html

has an error when replacing

```
window.onload(start())
```

with

```
window.addEventListener('load', start())
```

(see http://enclick.com/widgets/freelancer/test.html for reference)

Comment: Your use of `onload` wouldn't work anyways. And in either case, they accept a function reference, which is probably not returned by calling `start`. You should probably have `window.addEventListener('load', start)`

Comment: Perhaps clock1.js isn't getting loaded into the DOM in time. Try having it as a separate source.

Comment: Would be handy, if you have an error, to also put the error in the question... `Uncaught ReferenceError: startclock is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.onload = start;
```

or

```
window.addEventListener('load', start);
```

I took a look at your updated example and you could use the exact code like my example like this:

```
window.onload = startclock;
```

instead of this:

```
window.onload = function(){startclock();}
```

Comment: Then the issue has nothing to do with this block of code.  Your code must be broken somewhere else, or is not executing things in the correct order.

Comment: Your examples are also now offline, so I can't inspect anything.

Comment: I'm pointing out that you blindlessly copied `window.onload()`, which isn't the correct way of setting the window's `load` handler. And I'm not the OP. So you've failed to scroll up and see who the OP is.